# How to handle null exception for column values returned from controller in webgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I am developing an MVC application in which the Webgrid is used to show table columns. I have One primary table named Item and secondary table named Category. I am trying to bind Item table's columns into Webgrid of a View but getting exception inside webgrid while binding foreign table(Category) column.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Model

```
public class ItemModel   
{  
    public long id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> category_id { get; set; }          
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }   
}
```

Controller

```
List<ItemModel> lstItemModel = new List<ItemModel>();
List<Item> lstItemss = db.Items.ToList();
lstItemss.ForEach(x =>
{
    ItemModel stuModel = new ItemModel();
    stuModel.id= x.id;
    stuModel.Category = x.Category;
    lstItemModel.Add(stuModel);
});
return View(lstItemModel);
```

View inside webgrid I have

```
dataGrid.Column("Category", "Category", format: (Item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Category.name)?string.Empty:Item.Category.name)
```

You can see in the view I am handing null exception but still it generates exception in view for Item.Category.name where as Item.id gets bind without any issue.

Thanks a lot

Comment: in debug mode look the value of Item.Category, and then share with us

Comment: You not handling the case when `Category` is `null` - `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Item.Category.name)` will throw an exception if the value of `Category` is `null` because you cannot access the `name` proprty of `null`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments guys. Resolved the issue with this change that worked like charm.

Instead of this

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Category.name)
```

use this

```
(item.Category!= null)
```

so finally my view modified to

```
dataGrid.Column("Category", "Category", format: (Item) => (Item.Category==null)?string.Empty:Item.Category.name),
```

Comment: Or you could just do `stuModel.Category = x.Category ?? new Category()` and simplify the code in the view